# Controlling the response format from a REST service

Tags: c#, xml, rest, response

I have a REST service written in C# that can read in parameters and returns some values, but the XML doesn't have enough levels in it.

At the moment it returns:

```
<topNode>
    <item1>1</item1>
    <item2>2</item2>
    <item3>3</item3>
</topNode>
```

But what I really need is:

```
<topNode>
    <secondNode>
        <item1>1</item1>
        <item2>2</item2>
        <item3>3</item3>
    </secondNode>
</topNode>
```

I think that what I need to do is amend the response data contract, but I'm not sure how. At present it is written like so:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/myNamespace")]
public class dataResponse
{        
    [DataMember]
    public string item1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string item2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string item3 { get; set; }
}
```

As I also need to return XML with different element names if an error is encountered I'd ideally like to return an XML document that I can format myself.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Wait - what's the difference between what it returns now and what you need?  I'm missing something...

Comment: I forgot to add the second level to start with. Should look different now

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 special return types from a WCF method that give you more control over what is returned to the client:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message
Stream
byte[]
```

Stream and the byte array are simply going to return the data in the Stream or array to the client. For the message object you will need to use one of the static CreateMessage overloads in the Message object to create an instance of it to return. Using one of these return types, you will have to create the XML that is returned yourself, but I think that is what you are looking for here. For example you could do something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface: IMyContract
{
     [OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "getXml")]
     Stream ReturnAnyXml();   
}

public class MyService : IMyContract
{
    public Stream ReturnAnyXml()
    {
        WebOperationContext CurrentWebContext = WebOperationContext.Current;
        if (CurrentWebContext != null)
        {
            CurrentWebContext.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";    
            String AnyXml = "<tag></tag>";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AnyXml)); 
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: Looking on the net that seems to imply that SOAP will be returned rather than plain old XML. Is that correct or have I gone down the wrong route?

Comment: What binding are you using and what does your complete service contract look like ? Since you said it was a Rest service I presume that you are using either WebGet or WebInvoke methods.

Comment: I found that I could return the XmlElement and it did the job. Now I have something working I'm going to look to implement best practice and will investigate returning a stream rather than XmlElement