# How to return custom xml from WCF Rest Method?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, serialization

We use custom serialization schemas for xml serialization of our objects. I have a WCF REST Service written with the WCF Service Tempalte. I want to return our custom XML from this method however when i set the return to string, I instead get this :

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">

&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&lt;ReportResponse&gt;&lt;Status&gt;Success&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;Url&gt;http://pictor.blob.core.windows.net/pictor/ServiceTest.pdf&lt;/Url&gt;&lt;ReportRequestId&gt;00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&lt;/ReportRequestId&gt;&lt;/ReportResponse&gt;

</string>
```

As you can see my xml is wrapped in a html encoded string.. How do i return the appropriate xml response ?

Comment: Have you tried returning something like `XmlDocument` or `XElement` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964870/wcf-return-an-xmldocument

Comment: This would appear to be a duplicate or similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330197/controlling-the-response-format-from-a-rest-service/8336968#comment10286280_8336968).

Comment: XElement was the key here. Thanks Marc !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XElement as a response type allows me to return whatever xml I so choose. 
Credit for this answer goes to @Mark Gravell.